# Swtich statement syntax error

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to test if my user submits sensible data , which is later formatted to integer.
Where is the problem with the switch statement? :)

```
void convert(String str)
{
    int i=0;
    String x=str.startsWith();
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 0:
            int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println ("Should start with fixnumber");
    }
    System.out.println (i);
}
```

Comment: You're variable is a String and your testing to see if it's an int?! You're also not telling us the behavior. Are you seeing any errors? If so, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're switching on **x** which is a String - unless you're using Java 7, you can't use String in a Switch statement.

I expect the error is actually coming from **str.startsWith()**, where that method is expecting to take a String (which you're checking what it starts with) and returns a boolean, which you can't switch on either.

**UPDATE** Correcting your code to do what I think you're trying to do:

```
void convert(String str)
{
    int i = 0;
    switch (str.charAt(0)) {
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
        case '0':
            i = Integer.parseInt(str);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println ("Should start with fixnumber");
    }
    System.out.println (i);
}
```

Although the shorter way is just to do the **Integer.parseInt** call, and handling the NumberFormatException that may occur - then you don't need to do the switch at all.

```
void convert(String str)
{
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println (i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println ("Should start with fixnumber");
    }
}
```

You need to either **return i;** and convert the method signature from **void** to **int**, or otherwise expose the data in **i** to make it worthwhile.

Comment: yes, java complains about .startsWith(), as well as me trying to put a  boolean into the game. how would i get it work with java ? Help, appreciated!

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do ... if you're trying to convert the String into an int, then I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you're just printing to the console, there's no mandate to return `int`, but in general, it's a good idea to want to return what you're working with back to the function that called it.

Answer (score 1):

x is a string and in case you test number.
try:

```
case "string1"
..
break;
case "string2"
..
break;
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to test to see if the string entered *is* an Integer, then I see no reason to have the `switch()` in the first place.  It would be far better behavior to catch the exception raised when trying to work with the function.

Example:

```
void convert(String str) { // Heads-up:  convert has <package> visibility
    int i = 0;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println(i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println ("Should start with fixnumber");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` is a String.  The switch statement is attempting to compare it against integer values.  You need something like this:

```
switch (Integer.parseInt(x))
{
   // etc...
```

EDIT:  Actually, now that I see that the string is supposed to be the result of a startsWith call, I'm totally confused about what this code is trying to do.

Comment: I think the author is trying to test if the String starts with a number. Would be better IMO to skip the switch, do a parseInt and handle the formatting exception properly.

Comment: I am trying to parse the string using an unsuitable method, thanks for the charAt() and for the try catch, thanks !!!